# Continuous functions that coincide in dense set are equal

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Any corrections or feedback to the proof below will be highly appreciated.

*Proposition*. We have that $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ e $g\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions. Let $X_\alpha$ be a dense set in $\mathbb{R}$. If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X_\alpha$, then $f=g$.

*Proof*. As $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions, we have for every point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{f(x_n)}=f(x_0)$ for every sequence of points $(x_n)_n \in \Bbb R$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = x_0$, and analogous definition is valid for $g$.

Because $X_\alpha$ is dense, then $\overline{X_\alpha}=\mathbb{R}$, that is, we can find for every $z\in\mathbb{R}$ a sequence $(z_n)_n$ in $X_a$ such that $z_n\to z$.

Then for every $z\in\Bbb R$ we do exactly that, defining a sequence $(z_n)_n$ in $X_\alpha$ such that $z_n\to z$. And as $f$ and $g$ are both continuous, we say that we have $f(z_n)\to f(z)$ as well as $g(z_n)\to g(z)$.

And if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{f(z_n)}=f(z)$ e $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{g(z_n)}=g(z)$, then we have that

$$\forall \epsilon_1>0\ \exists n_f\in\mathbb{N}:\ n>n_f\implies \left|f(z_n)-f(z)\right|<\epsilon_1$$

and also

$$\forall \epsilon_2>0\ \exists n_g\in\mathbb{N}:\ n>n_g\implies \left|g(z_n)-g(z)\right|<\epsilon_2$$

We take $n_0=\min{(n_f,n_g)}$, and we have

$$n>n_0\implies \left|f(z_n)-f(z)\right|<\epsilon_1\ \text{e}\ \left|g(z_n)-g(z)\right|<\epsilon_2$$

We define $\varepsilon=\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2$, and therefore

$$\left|f(z_n)-f(z)\right| + \left| g(z_n)-g(z)\right|<\varepsilon$$

If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X_\alpha$, then $f(z_n)=g(z_n)$ for all natural $n$, because $z_n\in X_\alpha$. And by triangular inequality we have

$$\left|f(z)-g(z)\right|\leq \left|f(z_n)-f(z)\right| + \left| g(z_n)-g(z)\right|$$

But $\left|f(z)-g(z)\right|$ is absolute value, therefore

$$0\leq \left|f(z)-g(z)\right|<\varepsilon;\ \text{for all $\varepsilon>0$}$$

We claim that $0= \left|f(z)-g(z)\right|$, because if we assume the opposite, we would have $\left|f(z)-g(z)\right|= a >0$, then we could define $\varepsilon=\frac{a}{2}$ and find $a=\left|f(z)-g(z)\right|<\frac{a}{2}$, contradiction.

Hence,

$$0= \left|f(z)-g(z)\right|\implies f(z)=g(z)\ \text{for all $z\in\mathbb{R}$}$$

Ergo $f=g$. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

$\rule{10cm}{0.4pt}$

What if $X_\alpha$ is not a dense set?

If $X_\alpha$ is not dense set, that is, $\overline{X_\alpha} \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ is a proper subset. Well, this means that there is some $z\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $z\not\in\overline{X_\alpha}$, or yet, $z$ is not a limit point of $X_\alpha$, then there is no sequence $(z_n)_n$ of $X_\alpha$ such that $z_n\to z$.

Comment: First prove that limits of sequences in $\mathbf R$ are unique: if $a_n \to L$ and $a_n \to M$ then $L = M$.  Therefore when $f(z_n) \to f(z)$, $g(z_n) \to g(z)$, and $f(z_n) = g(z_n)$ for all $n$, you get $f(z) = g(z)$.  Your way of reaching that conclusion is more tedious than that.  What is it you are asking at the end when $X_\alpha$ is not a dense subset?

Comment: When you have $f(z_n)\to f(z)$ you also have $ g(z_n)\to f(z)$ because every $ f(z_n)$ $ is$ $ g(z_n$).... Line 10.

Comment: BTW you do not need to type \lim\limits. You can erase "\limits" and type only \lim .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you included the `general-topology` tag, I’ll point out that this is a special case of a much more general result that has a short, simple proof.

> **Theorem.** Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions from a space $X$ to a Hausdorff space $Y$, and let $D$ be a dense subset of $X$ such that $f\upharpoonright D=g\upharpoonright D$; then $f=g$.
>
> **Proof.** If not, there is an $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\ne g(x)$. $Y$ is Hausdorff, so there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ in $Y$ such that $f(x)\in U$ and $g(x)\in V$. Let $W=f^{-1}[U]\cap g^{-1}[V]$; clearly $x\in W$, so $W\ne\varnothing$, and the continuity of $f$ and $g$ ensures that $W$ is open in $X$, so $W\cap D\ne\varnothing$. Let $y\in W\cap D$; then by hypothesis $f(y)=g(y)$, but $f(y)\in U$, $g(y)\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$, so $f(y)\ne g(y)$. This contradiction shows that $f=g$. $\dashv$

It’s not hard to adapt this proof to your specific setting.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: @EduardoC.: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can simplify your proof a lot by denoting $h=f-g$. $h$ is continuous as the difference of two continuous maps. You then just have to prove that if a continuous map $h$ vanishes on a dense set $X_\alpha$, then $h$ vanishes on $\mathbb R$. Which is almost immediate. Take $a \in \mathbb R$. As $X_\alpha$ is dense, it exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of $X_\alpha$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$ and then

$$f(a) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = 0.$$

Comment: One thing to keep in mind about that simplification, which is natural in the OP's context, is that it does not work in a setting where functions take values in a space that does not have addition and subtraction, e.g., functions with values in an arbitrary metric space.  Then the proof really does need to work with the functions $f$ and $g$ separately.

Comment: I fully agree with your comment. However, as you said, it is far from the context of the initial question.